# wpf Treeview blank while using virtualization

Tags: wpf, treeview, virtualization

We are maintaining a List data structure. After list is prepared, we are assigning datasource to Treeview. We are applying 'Virtualization' property to 'True'. Initial structure is like below. After virtualization, visual portion is 53 items.

```
-Doc
    -Chap1
        Page1
        Page2
        ...
        Page1000
```

Then we are trying to add one more item called "Chap2" with 500 sub items ("Pages") to "Doc" node at run time and then setting vertical scroll position to last sub item.

Problem: We are getting blank treeview after this operation.

Please suggest that do we need to change any properties or anything we need to do?

Comment: Are you binding to observablecollections? Post some code please.

Comment: Yes we are binding to observable collection.Below is the piece of XAML Code <TreeView MouseMove="eventTreeViewMouseMove" PreviewMouseWheel="eventTreeMouseWheel" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisual}" x:Uid="TreeView_1"  Selector.IsSelected="False" Background="White" x:Name="tvDocDisplay" PreviewKeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" PreviewKeyUp="eventTreeViewKeyUp" Drop="eventTreeViewDrop"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ContentScroll="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

Comment: Please post code in the question, edit it. Where is the ItemSource, how do you feed the treeview? And the item datatemplate?